# Split WP install between 2 databases?

Tags: database, mysql, server

Is it possible for Wordpress to work from two databases?

The reason I ask is that we're approaching our 100mb limit for database size on our host (1and1) but have up to 100 databases, so what I was hoping to do is essentially 'add on' another database for when the limit is reached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but that is out of *quick and easy* realm.

See [HyperDB in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/HyperDB) [and repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/) for starters.

Comment: Do you know if it will split a table at all as the bulk of the database is taken up by the posts table.

Comment: @Vince Pettit sorry, no hands-on experience with it. It's what wordpress.com uses so is usually first thing to point at.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the info, been reading up on it and seems to do what I want... will give it a try and take it from there!