# Split a database will improve performance?

Tags: multisite, database, mysql, split

Hi to all I'm running a Wordpress MS installation and I would like to move a couple of heavy "sub" blogs on a different DB, will it encrease my performances? Actually I'm on a dedicated server with quadcore 2.5 Ghz, 6GB ram and a few nice stuff like Lightspeed eaccelerator and so on. I'm a "self made webmaster" so I need an easy to follow guide that can teach me how to split safely my DB and improve my performance.
Thank you very much for this!
(just read: [Split WP install between 2 databases?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/split-wp-install-between-2-databases) is this the only solution available or there is an easier one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPMUdev has a [Multi-DB plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db/installation/) but you won't see any performance gains from splitting your database up unless you have a very high volume of sites with thousands of tables.

From the plugin instructions:

> Step 1:  Decide how many databases you
>   want (16, 256, 4096)
>
> So, how do you know that this plugin
>   is necessary for your install?   Well,
>   there are several factors to consider
>   beyond the scope of this  walkthrough,
>   but as a basic guideline:
>
> 1-5,000 blogs/sites you should be fine
>   with your WordPress default database
>
> 5,000 - 50,000 blogs/sites - go with
>   16 databases
>
> 50,000 - 100,000 blogs/sites - use 256
>   databases
>
> 100,000+ blogs/sites - use 4096
>   databases

Comment: As plugin says I don't need it actually, I have only 10/12 blogs installed but my DB is more then 150 MB....Anyway I have added Varnish cPanel plugin and now my website is faster :-)